# Precompute first part of sequence to accelerate computation

Tags: c++, optimization

I have to repeatedly evaluate the following function as part of an MCMC chain. It evaluates a weighted cumulative sum and consumes about 80% of compute time.

```
void method1(int n, double* x, double* y) {
    double z = 0;  // Weighted running total.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // Evaluate weighting factor.
        const int j = n - i;
        const double factor = 1 / sqrt(j * (j + 1));
        // Set next result.
        y[i] = z - factor * j * x[i];
        // Update running total.
        z += factor * x[i];
    }
    y[n] = z;
}
```

Running this in a loop 100m times for `n = 20` takes about 2.2 seconds on my machine (about 10ms variability between runs).

The "expensive" operation here is to calculate the weighting factor, and I can precompute the factors before starting the MCMC chain.

```
double FACTORS[N_PRECOMPUTED] = ...;

void method2(int n, double* x, double* y) {
    double z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        const int j = n - i;
        const double factor = FACTORS[j];
        y[i] = z - factor * j * x[i];
        z += factor * x[i];
    }
    y[n] = z;
}
```

Running the same benchmark, it takes about 1.1 seconds which seems a worthwhile improvement. However, this of course blows up when `n > N_PRECOMPUTED`. While `n` is typically small (order of tens), the program should run for any `n`.

The next logical step is to pre-compute the first part of the sequence and evaluate the rest on the fly if required.

```
void method3(int n, double* x, double* y) {
    double z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        const int j = n - i;
        const double factor = j < N_PRECOMPUTED ? FACTORS[j] : evaluate_factor(j);
        y[i] = z - factor * j * x[i];
        z += factor * x[i];
    }
    y[n] = z;
}
```

This yields some improvement with `N_PRECOMPUTED = 10`: 1.8 seconds but not as impressive as the 50% reduction for the pure lookup. It runs in 1.5 seconds if I set `N_PRECOMPUTED = 20` such that it could, in principle, look up all values.

Is there a better way to handle the decision to look up or compute the factor on the fly in `method3` to get closer to the performance of `method2`?

Comment: You have a common term `factor * x[i]`, but due to the different ordering of your `double` multiplications this probably won't be optimized by the compiler. Consider pre-computing that value, then doing `y[i] = z - j * weighted_x; z += weighted_x;` .. that is, if the slight differences in precision don't make this approach non-viable for you. Beware of your off-by-one bug in the table lookup in `method3`.

Comment: Correction: no off-by-one bug. I did not read it correctly.

Comment: Side note: consider storing x and y in a single datastructure and passing a vector of those pairs instead, it might pay off for large number of elements.

Comment: Side note: no it won't. Interleaving x & y is BAD for performance. Always prefer structures of arrays, rather than arrays of structures.

Comment: @robthebloke I'd say "try and measure in the right context". While I generally agree with your statement, I've seen situations where exactly the opposite was true.

Comment: for something that takes 80% of the runtime you could probably precompute up to n = 10,000 safely.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a hybrid strategy, where you calculate a few factors on the fly while taking advantage of precomputed factors as much as possible. Here's a modified version of `method3`:

```
void method4(int n, double* x, double* y) {
    double z = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    // Handle the initial precomputed factors if available
    for (; i < N_PRECOMPUTED && i < n; ++i) {
        const int j = n - i;
        const double factor = FACTORS[j];
        y[i] = z - factor * j * x[i];
        z += factor * x[i];
    }

    // Calculate and store remaining factors on-the-fly
    for (; i < n; ++i) {
        const int j = n - i;
        const double factor = evaluate_factor(j);
        y[i] = z - factor * j * x[i];
        z += factor * x[i];
    }

    y[n] = z;
}
```

This method first iterates through the precomputed factors if they are available and then calculates the remaining factors on-the-fly. This way, you take advantage of precomputed factors when possible and fall back to on-the-fly calculation when necessary. The exact performance improvement will depend on the distribution of n values and how many factors can be precomputed, but it should be more efficient than method3.

You can adjust `N_PRECOMPUTED` based on your typical use cases and available memory to find the optimal trade-off between precomputation and on-the-fly calculation.